# Ubuntu server USB mount

Tags: server, usb

I have configured my Raspberry PI 2 with Ubuntu Server 16.04.1, which is working like a charm.

My only issue is that my external HDD is not automatically mounted. I tried using the fstab and UUID, not working. I was reading that on Ubuntu server, you need USBMount. the only thing is that I want that drive to be mounted on /media/NAS

For now, I did a schedule cron job to mount the drive.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks :)

edit:

```
[   23.834487] audit: type=1400 audit(1455208086.487:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lxd/lxd-bridge-proxy" pid=887 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.842573] audit: type=1400 audit(1455208086.495:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=888 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.842655] audit: type=1400 audit(1455208086.495:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=888 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   24.394638] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
[   28.213436] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:758: group 1, block bitmap and bg descriptor inconsistent: 1258 vs 1257 free clusters
[   28.237744] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = mmcblk0p2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
[   29.169243] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   29.169478] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   30.828279] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   30.829360] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
```

DF:

```
df: /media/NAS: Transport endpoint is not connected
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            448M     0  448M   0% /dev
tmpfs            93M  8.3M   84M   9% /run
/dev/mmcblk0p2  7.0G  3.5G  3.5G  50% /
tmpfs           461M     0  461M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           461M     0  461M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  128M   56M   72M  44% /boot/firmware
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: Ok, can you please unmount the drive, then unplug, and plug it back in again, then post a fresh `dmesg | tail`?  Also, is this drive an SSD (or was it previously?)

Comment: I will do so tomorrow after work. it has been never an SSD, it was an HDD connected to a windows server 2008 R2 (4TB, GPT). I'll let you know

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt-get install usbmount`

It creates entries for usb devices in `/media`, then automounts the USB devices there.

Beware of FAT & NTFS drives, you may need to edit the `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf` file for filesystems that aren't supported by default.  Everything is commented well, so should be simple to do.

You may also need to `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` for NTFS support etc.

ext3 and ext4 (for example) should be fine.

Once installed, you can edit lines 12 & 13 of `/etc/usbmount/usbmount.conf`, changing the mount points to `/media/NAS` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but when I boot, the drive isn't connected when I do a DF -h. it seems the drive is mounted no where...

Comment: Mounted to nowhere? Can you be more specific?  What does your `df -h` look like? and can you post the output of `dmesg | tail` after you plug in a device?

Comment: Actually, I am remotely connect to my PI. The drive is connected at boot. See first post for the new details you asked me!

Comment: oh and to let you know, if I try to mount it manually, it says it's already mounted, but can't find the folder.. I do umount, the mount, it works to media/NAS. Thanks again for your help!